# Not able to use custom xml attributes from library project in android

Tags: android

I am using a library project in my app.It has custom xml attributes.Now i want to include this library project as a jar.When i include it as jar,in xml am not able to use the custom attributes.It throws an error : "No resource found in the given package".I tried including custom namespace : "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto".But it still throws the same error.I also tried adding the library project package name instead of "res-auto" in the namespace.But still it did not work.
Can you please tell me how to solve the above error.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a library project in my app.It has custom xml attributes. Now i want to include this library project as a jar

That is not possible. Your Android library project needs resources; a JAR does not contain Android resources.

> Can you please tell me how to solve the above error.

Do not use the custom attributes, and pray that the library project does not need any other resources.

Or, stick with your original current Android library project setup.

Or, if you are using Android Studio and/or Gradle for Android, you could package the library project as an AAR and use that from your app.